# Css footer on media print

Tags: css, asp.net, printing, footer

I am trying to print my web page as a report. I have done css for screen and different for print mode to be able when i pres CTRL+P to print it.

My problem is when I have 2 pages the footer doesn't move to go on page 2 bottom.

How I can do this?

css:

```
#footer{
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0%;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   border-top: 1px solid black;
}
#total{
    bottom:85%;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:62%;
    margin-bottom:2%;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;

}

#custsign{
    margin-left:60%;
    margin-top:-10%;
    padding-top:3%;
}
#compsign{
    padding-top:0.3%;
    margin-left:80%;
    margin-top:-2.4%;
}

/*#grid{
    padding-bottom:30%;
}*/
```

aspx:

```
 <div id="footer">
       <div id="total">
        <asp:Label ID="SubLabel" runat="server" Text="Sub Total: " ></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="SubText"  runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="DiscLabel" runat="server" Text="Discount: " ></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="DiscText"  runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="VatLabel" runat="server" Text="V.A.T.: " ></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="VatText"  runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
        <br />
         <asp:Label ID="TravelLabel" runat="server" Text="Travel Exp.: " ></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="TravelText"  runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="CurrencyLabel" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="TotalLabel" runat="server" Text="Amount Due: " Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="TotalText"  runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
            <br />
           </div>

            <asp:Label ID="ItemsLabel" runat="server" Text="Total No.Items: " ></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="ItemsText"  runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
        <br />
           <asp:Label ID="PrevBalanceLabel" runat="server" Text="Prev Balance: " ></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="PrevBalanceText"  runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
        <br />
         <asp:Label ID="NewBalanceLabel" runat="server" Text="New Balance: " ></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="NewBalanceText"  runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>

               <div id="custsign">
           <asp:Label ID="CustomerSignLabel" runat="server" Text="Customer" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                   </div>
                <div id="compsign">
         <asp:Label ID="CompanieSignLabel" runat="server" Text="Companie Ltd" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
            </div>
          </div>
```

example files:   [image: with div grid]
[image: without div grid]

**UPDATE with position:fixed**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about to use the code of this example?

[Make an Editable/Printable HTML Invoice](https://css-tricks.com/html-invoice/)

Answer (score 0):

You can change `position: absolute` to `position: fixed` on your #footer selector.

```
<style>

    @media screen {
        #footer {
            position: absolute;
            /*Other styles...*/
        }
    }

    @media print {
        #footer {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            /*Other styles...*/
        }
    }

</style>
```

This change will make your #footer repeat itself on every page.